# Grabing heading for each scraped section

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm scraping a bank's earnings release site to grab the PDF link for each quarters release. Each quarterly section has a header (e.g.:First Quarter 2020, etc). I'm having no problem getting the report, but I also want that sections header as well for each report. Here's what I have so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib3


def scraper():

    urllib3.disable_warnings()

    FITBurl = "https://ir.53.com/annual-and-quarterly-results"

    FITBr = requests.get(url=FITBurl, verify=False)

    FITBsoup = BeautifulSoup(FITBr.text,'html.parser')

    #finds quarter name
    quarter = FITBsoup.find_all("h4")[0].text 
    print(quarter)  # I want this respective 'quarter' name for each earnings release

    mylist = {}
    for items in FITBsoup.find_all("div", class_="filefield-file"): #add [0:5] to the end to just get the latest
        for x in items.select("a"):
            title = x.text.strip()
            name = x['title'][:-4]
            if title == 'Quarterly Earnings Release':
                link = x['href']
                print(f'{title} {name}: {link}') # ideally quarter name would replace 'name'
                mylist[name] = link

scraper()
```

I've tried to add it into my loop but then it just produces all the output for each 'h4' heading which isn't right. This seems simple, but it's really throwing me for a loop. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following css selector and then iterate.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib3


def scraper():

    urllib3.disable_warnings()

    FITBurl = "https://ir.53.com/annual-and-quarterly-results"

    FITBr = requests.get(url=FITBurl, verify=False)

    FITBsoup = BeautifulSoup(FITBr.text,'html.parser')

    for item in FITBsoup.select('.view-inner-wrapper'):
    #finds quarter name
        quarter = item.select_one("h4").text
        print(quarter) 

        mylist = {}
        for items in item.find_all("div", class_="filefield-file"): #add [0:5] to the end to just get the latest
            for x in items.select("a"):
                title = x.text.strip()
                name = x['title'][:-4]
                if title == 'Quarterly Earnings Release':
                  link = x['href']
                  print('{} {}: {}'.format(title,name,link)) # ideally quarter name would replace 'name'
                  mylist[name] = link

scraper()
```

**Output**:

```
First Quarter 2020
Quarterly Earnings Release Q1_2020_Earnings_Release_-_Final: https://ir.53.com/sites/53-e.investorhq.businesswire.com/files/report/additional/Q1_2020_Earnings_Release_-_Final.pdf
Fourth Quarter 2019
Quarterly Earnings Release Q4_2019_Earnings_Release: https://ir.53.com/sites/53-e.investorhq.businesswire.com/files/report/additional/Q4_2019_Earnings_Release.pdf
Third Quarter 2019
Quarterly Earnings Release FITB_3Q19_Quarterly_Earnings_Release: https://ir.53.com/sites/53-e.investorhq.businesswire.com/files/report/additional/FITB_3Q19_Quarterly_Earnings_Release.pdf
Second Quarter 2019
Quarterly Earnings Release FITB_2Q19_Quarterly_Earnings_Release: https://ir.53.com/sites/53-e.investorhq.businesswire.com/files/report/additional/FITB_2Q19_Quarterly_Earnings_Release.pdf
First Quarter 2019
Quarterly Earnings Release FITB_1Q19_Earnings_Release: https://ir.53.com/sites/53-e.investorhq.businesswire.com/files/report/additional/FITB_1Q19_Earnings_Release.pdf
Fourth Quarter 2018
Quarterly Earnings Release 4Q18_Fifth_Third_Bancorp_Earnings_Release: https://ir.53.com/sites/53-e.investorhq.businesswire.com/files/report/additional/4Q18_Fifth_Third_Bancorp_Earnings_Release.pdf
Third Quarter 2018
Quarterly Earnings Release Fifth_Third_Bancorp_3Q18_Earnings_Release: https://ir.53.com/sites/53-e.investorhq.businesswire.com/files/report/additional/Fifth_Third_Bancorp_3Q18_Earnings_Release.pdf
Second Quarter 2018
Quarterly Earnings Release FITB_2Q18_Earnings_Release: https://ir.53.com/sites/53-e.investorhq.businesswire.com/files/report/additional/FITB_2Q18_Earnings_Release.pdf
First Quarter 2018
Quarterly Earnings Release 1Q18_FITB_Earnings_Release: https://ir.53.com/sites/53-e.investorhq.businesswire.com/files/report/additional/1Q18_FITB_Earnings_Release.pdf
Fourth Quarter 2017
Quarterly Earnings Release 4Q17_FITB_Earnings_Release_1: https://ir.53.com/sites/53-e.investorhq.businesswire.com/files/report/additional/4Q17_FITB_Earnings_Release_1.pdf
Third Quarter 2017
Quarterly Earnings Release FITB_3Q17_Earnings_Release_1: https://ir.53.com/sites/53-e.investorhq.businesswire.com/files/report/additional/FITB_3Q17_Earnings_Release_1.pdf
Second Quarter 2017
Quarterly Earnings Release Fifth_Third_Bancorp_-_2Q17_-_Earnings_Release_1: https://ir.53.com/sites/53-e.investorhq.businesswire.com/files/report/additional/Fifth_Third_Bancorp_-_2Q17_-_Earnings_Release_1.pdf
First Quarter 2017
Quarterly Earnings Release 1Q17_Earnings_Release_report_: https://ir.53.com/sites/53-e.investorhq.businesswire.com/files/report/additional/1Q17_Earnings_Release_report__0.pdf
Fourth Quarter 2016
Quarterly Earnings Release Fifth_Third_Bancorp_4Q16_Earnings_Release: https://ir.53.com/sites/53-e.investorhq.businesswire.com/files/report/additional/Fifth_Third_Bancorp_4Q16_Earnings_Release.pdf
Third Quarter 2016
Quarterly Earnings Release 3Q16_Earnings_Release_FINAL: https://ir.53.com/sites/53-e.investorhq.businesswire.com/files/report/additional/3Q16_Earnings_Release_FINAL.pdf
Second Quarter 2016
Quarterly Earnings Release Earnings_Release_2Q16_FINAL: https://ir.53.com/sites/53-e.investorhq.businesswire.com/files/report/additional/Earnings_Release_2Q16_FINAL.pdf
First Quarter 2016
Quarterly Earnings Release FITB_1Q16_Earnings_Release: https://ir.53.com/sites/53-e.investorhq.businesswire.com/files/report/additional/FITB_1Q16_Earnings_Release.pdf
Fourth Quarter 2015
Quarterly Earnings Release 4Q15_Earnings_Release_Final: https://ir.53.com/sites/53-e.investorhq.businesswire.com/files/report/additional/4Q15_Earnings_Release_Final.pdf
Third Quarter 2015
Quarterly Earnings Release 3Q15_Earnings_Release_Final: https://ir.53.com/sites/53-e.investorhq.businesswire.com/files/report/additional/3Q15_Earnings_Release_Final.pdf
Second Quarter 2015
Quarterly Earnings Release 2Q15_Earnings_Release_Final: https://ir.53.com/sites/53-e.investorhq.businesswire.com/files/report/additional/2Q15_Earnings_Release_Final.pdf
First Quarter 2015
Quarterly Earnings Release FITB_1Q15_Earnings_Release: https://ir.53.com/sites/53-e.investorhq.businesswire.com/files/report/additional/FITB_1Q15_Earnings_Release_0.pdf
Fourth Quarter 2014
Quarterly Earnings Release Earnings_Release_4Q14: https://ir.53.com/sites/53-e.investorhq.businesswire.com/files/report/additional/Earnings_Release_4Q14.pdf
Third Quarter 2014
Quarterly Earnings Release 3Q14_FITB_Earnings_Release: https://ir.53.com/sites/53-e.investorhq.businesswire.com/files/report/additional/3Q14_FITB_Earnings_Release.pdf
Second Quarter 2014
Quarterly Earnings Release 2Q14_Earnings_Release_FINAL: https://ir.53.com/sites/53-e.investorhq.businesswire.com/files/report/additional/2Q14_Earnings_Release_FINAL.pdf
First Quarter 2014
Quarterly Earnings Release 1Q14_Earnings_Release_Final_with_Back_Tables1: https://ir.53.com/sites/53-e.investorhq.businesswire.com/files/report/additional/1Q14_Earnings_Release_Final_with_Back_Tables1.pdf
Fourth Quarter 2013
Quarterly Earnings Release FITB_Q414_Earnings_Release: https://ir.53.com/sites/53-e.investorhq.businesswire.com/files/report/additional/FITB_Q414_Earnings_Release.pdf
Third Quarter 2013
Quarterly Earnings Release FITB_Release_3Q13_FINAL_with_Tables: https://ir.53.com/sites/53-e.investorhq.businesswire.com/files/report/additional/FITB_Release_3Q13_FINAL_with_Tables.pdf
Second Quarter 2013
Quarterly Earnings Release 2Q13EarningsReleaseFINAL2: https://ir.53.com/sites/53-e.investorhq.businesswire.com/files/report/additional/2Q13EarningsReleaseFINAL2.pdf
First Quarter 2013
Quarterly Earnings Release FITB_1Q13_Earnings_Release: https://ir.53.com/sites/53-e.investorhq.businesswire.com/files/report/additional/FITB_1Q13_Earnings_Release.pdf
Fourth Quarter 2012
Quarterly Earnings Release 4Q12_Earnings_Release_Final1: https://ir.53.com/sites/53-e.investorhq.businesswire.com/files/report/additional/4Q12_Earnings_Release_Final1.pdf
Third Quarter 2012
Quarterly Earnings Release 3Q12_Earnings_Release_FINAL: https://ir.53.com/sites/53-e.investorhq.businesswire.com/files/report/additional/3Q12_Earnings_Release_FINAL_0.pdf
Second Quarter 2012
Quarterly Earnings Release 2Q12_Earnings_Release_final: https://ir.53.com/sites/53-e.investorhq.businesswire.com/files/report/additional/2Q12_Earnings_Release_final.pdf
First Quarter 2012
Quarterly Earnings Release FITB-1Q12_Earnings_Release_FINAL2: https://ir.53.com/sites/53-e.investorhq.businesswire.com/files/report/additional/FITB-1Q12_Earnings_Release_FINAL2.pdf
```

Comment: This is great, thank you! I wasn't aware of select_one. Awesome!